# Display loading gif while java code on jsp site is performed

Tags: html, css, jsp

I found much similar things, but none which actually fits into my wishes.

I have got one jsp where at the beginning is java code which actually takes 10-30 seconds to be finished (i am getting something from a database and build charts) and i want to add a nice loading image in the middle of the page and make it fade off when it has finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a straight forward solution. But, it is able to achieve your requirement by using `iframe`.

My trials with single page jsp failed as the loading of the page didn't happen till the process inside JSP is finished.

Following is the workaround i used:

> 1. Create the main JSP (assume index.jsp) page where display part is handled

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Testing the loading</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function processRecords(){
        document.getElementById("mainContent").src = "process.jsp";
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="processRecords()">
    <iframe id="mainContent" width="100%" style="border: none" seamless src="loader.jsp"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

> 2. Create a JSP/HTML (assume loader.jsp) with loader display part

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Processing</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="images/loader.gif" style="position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

> 3. Create a JSP (assume process.jsp) with actual processing & results display

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Processing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        //Following is a manual sleep simulating a process 
        try {
            //Sleep for 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            out.write("Error occurred while processing");
        }
        out.write("Done!");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

> 4. Working

When main JSP page (index.jsp) loads it will be loading with `iframe` src pointing to the loader JSP page (loader.jsp). So, initially the loader gif image will be displayed. The `onload` method in main JSP page invokes a javascript which in turn invokes the actual processing JSP page (process.jsp). Till the processing JSP page returns results the loader page in `iframe` won't be replaced simulating, thus simulating the loading before processing in Java code.

Comment: Thanks, ima try it out, my solution which i made for testing puroses was that i created a index.html which only displays a gif and calls the jsp site, the gif is displayed until the java code is fully executed. It works but it isnt as great as yours (if it works)